# put isset($_GET('start') it wont display the next page on paging.php

Tags: php

```
$page_name= (isset($_POST['page_name'])); 
@$limit=$_GET['limit'];

if(strlen($limit) > 0 and !is_numeric($limit)){
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
}
switch($limit)
{
    case 2:
        $select2="selected";
        $select10="";
        $select5="";
        break;

    case 5:
        $select5="selected";
        $select10="";
        $select2="";
        break;

    default:
        $select10="selected";
        $select5="";
        $select2="";
        break;
}

$start=($_GET['start']);  // THIS PART!//

if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start)){
    echo "Data Error111";
    exit;
}

$eu = ($start - 0); 

if(!$limit > 0 ){ 
    $limit = 10;    
}              

$this1 = $eu + $limit; 
$back = $eu - $limit; 
$next = $eu + $limit; 

$query=" SELECT * FROM tblename  ";
$result=mysql_query($query);

echo mysql_error();
$nume=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query=" SELECT * FROM tblname  limit $eu, $limit ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();
<?php while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['country']; ?></td>
<?php
    if($back >=0) { 
    print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back&limit=$limit'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
} 

echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";

$i=0;
$l=1;

for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
    if($i <> $eu){
        echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i&limit=$limit'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$l</font></a> ";
    }
    else { 
        echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$l</font>";
    }        
    $l=$l+1;
}

echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";

if($this1 < $nume) { 
    print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next&limit=$limit'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";
} 
echo "</td></tr></table>";
?>
```

sory guys..like this if i add isset to start to defined $start variable, when i run it it display the the data let's say 10 country name, but when i click next to display the page 2, it come out with the same country name in page 1 not other name in page 2,if i don't put isset to $start it display the 10 country on page 1 and when i click next to view the page 2 it success to display other different 10 country name, so how suppose i do? and what mistake i have to correct?

Comment: The question is not clear enough for me to try to answer.

Comment: When it jumps to data error print the value of `$start`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$start=($_GET['start']);
```

to

```
$start=1;//some default value
if(isset($_GET['start']))
 $start=$_GET['start'];
```

Comment: thanks amit...it success...and sorry guys if u don't understand my question